# What is the prerequisite for Freitag's complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, book-recommendation

I'd like to read Freitag's complex analysis because it contains interesting topics such as the proof of prime number theorem and elliptic functions and Dirichlet series, etc.
But after skimming for a moment, I realized that it uses some method which I don't learn yet to prove theorems. i.e I don't know that Jacobi map is isomorphic when it comes to from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. (What subject can I learn this thing?)

So is it okay for me , keep reading this book or find another one? if you recommends reading another one, could you recommends introductory complex analysis book containing interesting applications?

Comment: Oh, by all means read that book: it is excellent! whenever you meet a problem, try to cope with it reading in the net of other books, or just skip it. You're going to need a hefty background in real analysis, but for elliptic functions et al. you're going to need linear and abstract algebra, number theory and etc. All in all, I'd say that an advanced undergraduate student can make it through most of the book.

Comment: @DonAntonio thank you for your kind answer. Unfortunately, I don't learn abstract algebra yet and still learning linear algebra at the same time. Considering your answer, it's more appropriate to change book for main reference but remain this book as secondary. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, perhaps that'd be better for you, in particular if you're thinking of taking a course in complex functions. Something simpler may be the best.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks a lot. It's very helpful advice for me. Have a good day!